# Deleting and then undeleting answer gave me a point

Tags: bug

I just answered a question, and then realised I had misread the question. So I deleted my answer as it wasn't correct or applicable.

Then I edited my deleted answer to answer the question properly before un-deleting the answer, and my account is showing +1 point. I looked at the reputation log and there isn't any event recorded.

Is this a bug?

This is the question:

[Can I use something other than dynamic_cast in this design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216752/can-i-use-something-other-than-dynamic-cast-in-this-design/32216836)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't lose any reputation for deleting your answer, nor gained any by undeleting it. Your answer has no votes on it. What happened is that someone else deleted their answer which you had downvoted, so your 1 reputation cost for downvoting it was refunded to you.

You should be able to see that removal event. Make sure you have the box next to "show removed posts" checked at the bottom of your reputation history.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. It was just the timing combined with not knowing about that check box.